# How do i install opengl? My graphics drivers are all installed and updated, along with java

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Here is what comes up.

```
    ---- Minecraft Crash Report ---- // Everything's going to plan. No, really, that was supposed to happen.

    Time: 12/24/14 4:50 PM Description: Initializing game

    org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated 
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method) 
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52) at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252) 
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306) 
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848) 
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757) 
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739) 
at bss.an(SourceFile:526) at bss.ak(SourceFile:355) 
at bss.a(SourceFile:302) 
at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

    A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

    -- Head --
 Stacktrace:
 at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method) 
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52) 
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252) 
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306) 
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848) 
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757) 
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739) 
at bss.an(SourceFile:526) 
at bss.ak(SourceFile:355)

    -- Initialization -- 
Details: 
Stacktrace: 
at bss.a(SourceFile:302) 
at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

    -- System Details --
Details: Minecraft Version: 1.8.1 
Operating System: Windows 8.1 (x86) version 6.3 
Java Version: 1.8.0_25, Oracle Corporation 
Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation 
Memory: 99695424 bytes (95 MB) / 156512256 bytes (149 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB) 
JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M 
IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0 
Launched Version: 1.8.1 
LWJGL: 2.9.1 
OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ 
RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread. 
GL Caps: Using 
VBOs: No 
Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched. 
Type: Client (map_client.txt) 
Resource Packs: [] 
Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null 
Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
```

Comment: You don't install OpenGL.  Your graphics card either supports it or doesn't.  What kind of graphics card are you using?  Are you using an integrated card?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here: http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/pixel-format-not-accelerated/

If it's really not an outdated graphics driver (maybe you could try to re-install it - "clean installation"), I think you've set some java arguments yourself. :)

Comment: Well I haven't done anything to it but make sure my video card drivers are up to date

Comment: @user96498: Not just update. Remove the driver completely and install it from scratch.